# What is a "loose character" in Indian English?

Tags: subcontinental-english

What does the phrase "loose character" in Indian English mean?

E.g. "He is a loose character", or, "He has a loose character"

Comment: In American English "is a loose character" and "has a loose character" would have significantly different connotations.

Comment: @HotLicks interesting! Please, go on!

Comment: It has nothing to do with Indian English or American English. In English generally "a loose character" is an idiom implying an unreliable, or untrustworthy person.

Comment: @HotLicks If you look at my comment below the first answer you will see that "a loose character" is one of those words that can give rise to serious trans-Atlantic confusion. It is like "nervy", which means having nerves of steel, to an American, but of a nervous disposition, in Britain. To you a "loose character" may be easy-going and relaxed, but call someone that in Britain and you could be in trouble.

Comment: @WS2 - I never said "easy going".  As I said, there is not a single definition.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you understand by "a loose character" ?

Comment: @WS2 - In AE, "having a loose character" would imply a tendency toward immorality, but "being a loose character" simply implies a degree of impulsiveness and lack of self-control.

Comment: @HotLicks OED sense 3d of ***loose***: *Of persons, etc.: relaxed or easy, calm; uninhibited. Esp. predic. (quasi-adv.) in to hang (or stay) loose. slang (originally U.S.).* Example *1982   W. Safire in N.Y. Times Mag. 28 Nov. 16   The sympathetic farewell is undiminished: Hang in there vies with Hang tough and Hang loose, and Walk light may cheer up the overweight.* Does that make sense?

Comment: @WS2 - "Hang loose" is miles away from any meaning of "loose character".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> character (noun)
>
> the mental and moral qualities distinctive
>   to an individual.
>
> "running away was not in keeping with her character"
>
> — [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/character)

"Loose" is a literal translation of the Urdu/Hindi word *dheela*. It implies imperfect or bad. E.g. *kaam dheela kiya hai* i.e. "The work has been loosely done" implies that the task was ill-performed. Hindi/Urdu aren't very literal languages. (Personally, it drives me a little insane at times.)

"Loose character" means someone with bad moral qualities. It is most commonly used when talking about someone with a (perceived) history of extra-marital romantic relationships. Romantic relationships are not generally approved of by society in the sub-continent.

Comment: Google is not a valid reference.

Comment: @tchrist Says who? Google runs a dictionary service, which in this case can be accessed by running a search for "define character". Nothing in the [referencing](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) page disallows citing it.

Comment: It is not reproducible nor guaranteed. It us not a published source with an attributable publication date for archival purposes. You need a real dictionary. Can you imagine submitting a bibliographical reference entry in a professional journal that amounted to little more than "because Google said so"? Nobody would take you seriously. That's the point. And this has nothing to so with Indians.

Comment: If you look at the very bottom of the block in Google you will see “From Oxford”. That is the source of the information and what you should be citing. It’s not that you can’t use the information; you’re just not citing it properly.

Comment: @tchrist, that explanation makes sense, I'll update the citation, thank you. When did I ever say anything has anything to do with Indians? What do they have to do with anything?

Comment: Having had 40 years of talking with people from the Subcontinent, I support Amin Shah Gilani answer.

Comment: @Greybeard But there is no need to refer here to the Urdu/Hindi translation. Unless one were teaching a class of Urdu or Hindi speakers the information would be superfluous. By mentioning it, it suggests that the expression somehow or other originates from one of the Indian languages. "Loose character" is simply an English idiom, applicable whether one is in London, Mumbai, or Dallas.

Comment: Further to the above, I need to qualify what I have said. The Americans do apply the adjective "loose" to people to suggest "relaxed, calm, easy-going" etc. The OED confirms this. But it is not used that way in Britain.

Comment: @WS2 The question is "What does the phrase "loose character" **in Indian English** mean?" I didn't refer to the translation directly. The phrase "a loose character" is far commoner in Subcontinental English than in AE or BE. Compare **a loose character** with the uncommon **louche**
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+loose+character%2C+louche&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20loose%20character%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clouche%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20loose%20character%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clouche%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -2):

Quora reference of loose character https://www.quora.com/What-do-you-mean-by-loose-character; which reads like  ?

//To loose your character takes lowering your moral standards below a personal mental stopping point in turn changing the way you see yourself and in the process effecting the way people see you. in turn lowering the bar again changing the way you see your self repeat over and over until circumstances change or mental health becomes a issue.//

Comment: I have down voted as your answer as it is all but incomprehensible and does not reflect the meaning. "Loose" is an adjective and not a verb.